# TreeSet violating Set contract?

Tags: java, collections, treeset

I was trying to answer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17608422/i-am-able-to-insert-duplicate-entries-in-treeset-how-to-overcome-this/17608436?noredirect=1#comment25630834_17608436) question in the forum and I found that despite of overriding the `equals` method in the `Employee` class, I am still able to add duplicate elements to the `TreeSet`.

The Javadoc of [TreeSet.add(E)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#add%28E%29) method says

> Adds the specified element to this set if it is not already present.
>   More formally, adds the specified element e to this set if the set
>   contains no element e2 such that (e==null ? e2==null : e.equals(e2)).
>   If this set already contains the element, the call leaves the set
>   unchanged and returns false.

This essentially means that no 2 equals objects will be inserted into `TreeSet` and equality is determined solely by `equals()` method of contained objects.

However, below code is adding 2 elements to the `Set` even though they are equal

```
public class Employee implements Comparable<Employee> {

    String employeeName;
    int employeeId;

    public Employee(String name, int id) {
        this.employeeName = name;
        this.employeeId = id;
    }

    public int compareTo(Employee emp) {
        //return this.employeeName.compareTo(emp.employeeName);
        return (this.employeeId - emp.employeeId);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ("Name is: " + employeeName + " Emp id is: " + employeeId);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object emp) {
        if(emp instanceof Employee &&((Employee)emp).employeeName.equals(this.employeeName)){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Set<Employee> set = new TreeSet<Employee>();
        Employee e1 = new Employee("A", 1);
        Employee e2 = new Employee("A", 2);
        System.out.println(e1.equals(e2));
        set.add(e1);
        set.add(e2);
        System.out.println(set);
    }

}
```

And here is the output

```
true
[Name is: A Emp id is: 1, Name is: A Emp id is: 2]
```

**Why is `TreeSet` allowing multiple elements even if they are equal?**

Now I changed the `compareTo` method of `Employee` like this

```
public int compareTo(Employee emp) {
    return this.employeeName.compareTo(emp.employeeName);
}
```

And the output is

```
true
[Name is: A Emp id is: 1]
```

**How the `TreeSet` working properly after overriding `compareTo` ?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The javadoc of TreeSet also says:

> Note that the ordering maintained by a set (whether or not an explicit comparator is provided) must be *consistent with equals* if it is to correctly implement the `Set` interface. (See `Comparable` or `Comparator` for a precise definition of *consistent with equals*.) This is so because the `Set` interface is defined in terms of the `equals` operation, but a `TreeSet` instance performs all element comparisons using its `compareTo` (or `compare`) method, so two elements that are deemed equal by this method are, from the standpoint of the set, equal. The behavior of a set *is* well-defined even if its ordering is inconsistent with equals; it just fails to obey the general contract of the `Set` interface.

I agree that the javadoc of `add()` could make it clearer that `equals()` is not actually used, and re-state or link to this warning, though.

Comment: @sanbhat this is specified in `SortedSet` as well, and `TreeSet` implements `SortedSet`.

Comment: thanks @LuiggiMendoza i couldn't find it initially... i was looking for **ordering maintained by a set (whether or not an explicit comparator is provided) must be consistent with equals**

Answer (score 0):

`Set` implementations use a `Map` behind the scenes to manage the data and, in doing so, guarantee the uniqueness of an object through the `Map`'s key.

As far as I know, no explicit test of `equals` is done meaning that your object would be added if it were not explicitly the same object (i.e. '==').

I think the docs are misleading but I guess that it's saying it's the formal language representation. It's ambiguous so I Could be wrong but I'm pretty sure that uniqueness is guaranteed by virtue of the underlying map's keys. FYI: A dummy value is passed with your object as the key.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with the implementation of the `Set`. Note that `TreeSet` implements `NavigableSet` and `SortedSet` (refer [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html)) and `SortedSet` states to use [natural ordering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) (refer [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedSet.html)).

Answer (score 0):

First thing about TreeSet is, it also maintain order of object while stroing them and use compareTo method.

Because in your first version of compareTo method you are using employeeId for comparison and put diffrent emoplyee id for object e1 and e2.

Treeset will treat this as a different object as comparison doesn't send zero value (it will send either + or - value).

but in second verion you implement compareTo using employeeName, which is same for object e1 and e2.