# Cannot add objects to TreeSet

Tags: java, equals, treeset

When adding two `Order` objects to a `TreeSet` I see that the first is added, but the second is ignored. The implementation of the `Order.equals` method is shown below.
Both the objects definitely have different `orderId`s, but more importantly I placed a break point within the `equals` method and it did not get hit?!

My question is why would the second `Order` was added to the `TreeSet`. The only reason I can think of is that it had the same `orderId`, hence it would have been ignored, but this is definitely not the case.

```
private final long orderId;

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Order other = (Order) obj;
    if (orderId != other.orderId)
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

Comment: `TreeSet` doesn't work with `equals` and `hashCode` methods but with a `Comparator`.

Comment: But does'nt that break the Set<T> contract?

Comment: Read here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17608440/1065197

Comment: In this case, the equals and the compare method from the Comparator or compareTo method from Comparable interface should be consistent in order not to break the set contract.

Answer (score 2):

TreeSet uses the object's implemented `Comparable<Order>` or by a provided `Comparator<Order>` to determine equivalence.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html), `TreeSet` can also use the natural ordering, depending which constructor is used. Your way to override the equals method looks fine.